# How come instagram iOS app never ask me login again, even token is expired?

Tags: ios, token, instagram, expired-sessions

I have been searching this for days..... I know usually when we design token for client and server, user can login with username and password, server use them to create a token and send back. If token is expired, we let user login again.

How come when I use instagram and never see it needs me login again? How do they handle this on their mobile app?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For that you could simply store the username and password of user with keychain(along with encrypting). Then when token is not valid simply fetch the credentials from your keychain and make a login for new token.

Comment: I believe you are caching the access token? 

Go to iOS Simulator >>  Reset Content and Settings. Are you able to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram says:

> Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens have no explicit expiry, though your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access or we expire the token after some period of time. In this case, your response’s meta will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError”. In other words: do do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

If the token is somehow expired then they request for a new one, but that should be a rare case as instagram says they do no include an expiry time.

For more [info read this](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/). Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the access token and save that access token in your app, access token is not valid forever, so you should implement and handle this on your application follow this tutorial for login with instagram using oauth and its implementation on app side
http://codegerms.com/login-with-instagram-ios-application-objective-c/